# Use counter value as input of pgfmathparse

Tags: counters, pgfmath

I have a command that prints a number, which is based on a counter value. I am trying to use this number for further mathematical calculations.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}  
\newcommand{\foo}{
    \newcounter{bar}
    \setcounter{bar}{0}
    \stepcounter{bar}
    \thebar
}

% This does not work, but results in an endless loop
\pgfmathparse{\foo{}*0.3}

\end{document}
```

Apparently, this is not possible. Unfortunately, I do not manage to store the output of \foo as a numerical value in an additional variable, that can then be used by \pgfmathparse.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to remove `\thebar` from the definition of `\foo`, and do things something like `\foo\pgfmathparse{\thebar*2}`.  That is to say, you cannot be stepping counters *inside* of `\pgfmathparse`.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I thought Latex will expand \foo to the value of \bar. Isn't this true? Since \foo is defined in another file, I do not necessarily know the name of \bar. Is there any other possibility?

Comment: Okay, I see. Is there any way to achieve the same without referencing \thebar? \foo is defined in another file and \bar should be treated as a private variable.

Comment: By LaTeX convention, counters are not "private" (local) variables.  Thus, even if you step the counter `bar` inside of a group, `\thebar` will be available anywhere inside the document, as long as you did not declare the counter inside of the group.

Comment: Indeed. It works. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, I need to correct a prior comment...`\stepcounter` does not disappear as part of an expansion...it executes. That is, stepping a counter is not an expansion operation. Maybe define `\silentfoo` to be the version lacking output, and then define `\foo` as `{\silentfoo\thebar}`. Use `\silentfoo` immediately before the `\pgfmathparse` and `\thebar` inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize my comments in the form of an MWE answer.

Salient points: don't step a counter inside of `\pgfmathparse`; also, counters are global in LaTeX, so that `\thebar` is always available, even after being stepped inside a group; If you need a printing version of `\foo` outside of `\pgfmathparse`, then create two macros, such as `\foo` and `\silentfoo`.

BONUS tip: don't declare fixed counters inside of macros, unless you have a particular reason to do so.  You won't be able to call on the macro more than once.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\newcounter{bar}
\newcommand{\silentfoo}{\stepcounter{bar}}
\newcommand{\foo}{\silentfoo\thebar}
\begin{document}  
{\foo,\foo{} inside a group}

\silentfoo\pgfmathparse{\thebar*0.3}
\pgfmathresult{} should be 3*0.3
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding your bonus tip: In my original code I first check if the counter has already been defined. In that way it is possible to call the macro more than once.